# Using Slick (jQuery plugin) with Angular

Tags: jquery, node.js, angularjs, plugins, slick.js

I've created a website on a node environment with Angular as my front-end. I try to get a jQuery plugin working, but it only seems to work on Chrome (not FireFox, Safari or mobile devices). Now, I've read that using jQuery plugins together with Angular requires a different approach. How can I do this?

I have this plugin activated from my external scripts.js file.
This is the plugin I wish to use:

```
$('.usps-slider .sliding').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  centerMode: true,
  arrows: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 810,
      settings: {
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerPadding: 100,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        infinite: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)'s carousel.

There is an Angular directive version of Slick, that may want to use in your app: [Angular Slick carousel](http://devmark.github.io/angular-slick-carousel/#/).